# how to embed the powerBi report in html iFrame

Tags: html, powerbi

### This content cannot be displayed in a frame

---

```html
<p>
    <iframe style="border-width: 1px; border-color: #bbb; border-style: solid;" 
            src="https://app.powerbi.com/groups/me/dashboards/ba2bd959-2877-4b8d-ab97-986997bbe15b/qna"
            frameborder=""
            scrolling="no" 
            align="middle" 
            width="696" 
            height="588">
    </iframe>
</p>
```

Comment: Asking anywhere, especially in the title, for urgent help will not improve the likelihood of getting urgent help. Instead, spend a *little* time actually making your question better and you will get answers.

Answer (score 1):

Power BI does not currently support embedding QNA or Dashboards. You can embed tiles from a dashboard or reports.  The link describing how to do the latter two are here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/archive/2015/09/23/power-bi-api-updates-roundup.aspx

and here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbidev/archive/2015/12/02/power-bi-api-updates-roundup-december-2015.aspx

Answer (score 1):

From your Power BI workspace, select File->Publish to Web. Then it will show you the correct link to embed in your iframe. It will give you warnings about this not being secure. My PBI reports all run in an intranet so this is not an issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

Power BI now supports this feature.
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/easily-embed-secure-power-bi-reports-in-your-internal-portals-or-websites/#:~:text=The%20new%20Embed%20option%20is,HTML%20to%20add%20the%20report.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI introduces the feature for embed the PowerBI dashboard on your website via frame.

[Embed Power BI dashboard in website](https://fromjami.wordpress.com/2016/03/25/how-to-embed-the-powerbi-report-in-html-iframe/)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding Query Parameter - `?rs:embed=true`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/quickstart-embed

Comment: please make sure my edit is correct

Answer (score -2):

like facebook,twitter you also need to authenticate your web app.Due to security issue you can't load the powerbi in iframe.
For More 
[Steps integrating powerbi in web app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt143610.aspx)